# Jsoup: How to select one div tag without nested tag

Tags: jsoup

I have this two div tag show below

```
<div id="post_message_123456">
   <div class="quote">...</div>
....
</div>
```

My issue is how do I select this div without selecting div.quote

I tried this way:

```
System.out.println(e.select("div[id^=post_message]").text());
```

but it print out everything including div.quote. Do you have any workaround for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: could you please explain the usecase. What do you want to select in the parent excluding the children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the parent and remove the child div.

`Element elem = doc.getElementById("post_message_123456");
elem.getElementsByClass("quote").remove();`

Also have you seen elem.ownText(), which may help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yup I heard of ownText but the problem is within for loop.

Comment: what's the problem in `for` loop?